# When will Nativescript for Windows mature past the proof of concept stage?

Tags: nativescript

The readme.md at https://github.com/NativeScript/windows-runtime says that the Windows runtime for Nativescript is in proof of concept stage, and then lists what I understand to be very deep language features that are *not* implemented yet.

The tone on the https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-runtime-preview-for-windows-10 announcement seems a bit more enthusiastic about the current feature set.

Being able to use Nativescript on Windows Phone (and any other platform) is incredibly appealing.

Comment: I doubt it will ever be supported which seems stupid personally. People dont buy windows phones much because of the lack of appstore, so if more developers develop for the windows store, it would be more popular. So nativescript supporting windows phone/uwp would make sense yet people only see ios and android as the main/only phone os'

Comment: @mast3rd3mon , the same UI API as used on Windows Phone also works for programming ordinary Windows desktop programs, did I understand that right?If so, actually for advanced programmers, Nativescript would function as unifying UI API also for desktop apps - and that would in itself be a reason to give energy to Nativescript's Windows Phone mode.  Also, how complicated can it be to implement Windows Phone really, at least on the low level.. Probably a lot of work but still not that bad, in particular after as Telerik have done, have implemented the same for Android and iOS in the past.

Comment: I'm in total agreement with you, it would benefit nativescript a lot if they incorporate/support uwp apps. But it unfortunately looks like it will never happen so alternatives like cordova might be a better solution

Comment: @mast3rd3mon , wait, what are you basing your idea that it will never happen on? In https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/254 , Valentin suggests there were some design&implementation challenges. I opened the issue https://github.com/NativeScript/windows-runtime/issues/5 now to discuss that more in depth. Windows would be so important. I get an impression that both TJ and Valentin really want Windows support to happen. Also we open source developers can contribute fixes.

Comment: They would've already added it if they were going to do it. I've spoken to a couple of people who work at nativescript in the nativescript slack channel and node of them seem to think it will get added as apparently its a lot of work

Answer (score 2):

TJ, a core team member, recently posted on the forums about this:

> Hey @NezzaGrey,
>
> Thanks for reaching out, and awesome that you’re liking NativeScript :smile:. >Straight to the point though—we’re not actively working on UWP support because >1) it’s a ton of work to add a new platform and commit to supporting that >platform indefinitely, and 2) we’re not seeing nearly enough demand from our >community to justify taking on that work.
>
> That doesn’t mean that UWP support in NativeScript will never happen, but it’s >not coming in the short term because we’re just not seeing the demand. That can >always change though. I’d encourage you to add your use case to the GitHub >issue open for adding UWP support in NativeScript: >https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/254. Yes, the issue is >somewhat ancient, but we really do pay attention to well-thought-out comments >during roadmap discussions.
>
> I’ll note two other things. First, our initial work on making a Windows runtime >is completely open source and available on GitHub: >https://github.com/NativeScript/windows-runtime. We’d love to have community >?>help to make the new runtime a reality.
>
> Second, one option you have is to build your iOS and Android apps with >NativeScript and Angular, and to use our code sharing approaches (see ?>https://www.nativescript.org/blog/code-sharing-between-web-and-mobile-with->angular-and-nativescript1) to share your Angular code with other apps. You >could take that approach to share Angular code between your NativeScript apps >and your UWP apps if you use something like Electron. This approach isn’t >ideal, as you’d probably prefer to build a completely native UWP app, but it’s >something to consider if you’re open to using Electron.
>
> Anyways, hopefully you found some of this helpful. If you have any other >questions feel free to follow up.
>
> Source: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/windows-uwp-support/2659/3

Comment: Aha, right, https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/254 discusses the Windows support question in general and also the challenges encountered when attempting to implement it. I hope others are more enthusiastic than TJ and that Windows will happen soon :D